# Refresh sharepoint parent modal dialog on closing child popup

Tags: sharepoint-designer, client-object-model

I have a button in a modal popup, on clicking that button another modal popup opens on top of that. Now I want to refresh the containing page of parent modal dialog on closing child popup.

my code snippet in parent popup :

```
function OpenModalPopup(_url) {
        var options = {
            url: _url,
            title: "Modal Popup",
            allowMaximize: true,
            showClose: true,
            dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null, closewindow)
        };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }

    function closewindow() {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);        
    }
```

But it refreshes the full page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to implement the scenario.

1st popup code (from where the second popup opens) ~

HTML in Page 1 :

```
<input id="sampleButtonParent" type="button" value="Open Modal Popup" onclick="OpenModalPopup('http://sampleurl.com/')" />
```

JS in Page 1:

```
function OpenModalPopup(_url) {
    var options = {
        url: _url,
        title:  "Modal Popup",
        allowMaximize: true,
        showClose: true,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null, popupClose)
    };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

function popupClose(result, value) {
    if (result != 0)
        location.reload(true);
}
```

2nd popup code ~

HTML in Page 2:

```
<input type="button" id="sampleButtonChild" value="Cancel and Refresh" onclick="closePopup();" />
```

JS in Page 2:

```
function closePopup() {
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, 1);
    };
```

Alternatively if you are performing any calculation in the server side you can write this code-block in the button click event at the code-behind instead of writing 'JS in Page 2'

Code-Behind in Page 2:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "closeModalPopup", "SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(1, 1);", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is on CallBack refresh the dialog elements.

For example: on parent dialog load you might be executing `ready` function. Call that function once the child dialog closes

```
function closewindow() {
    //Child Closed
    RefreshParentElements();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is useful. I don't have enough reputation yet to vote it up. Otherwise would have done gladly :)

Comment: @AnirbanBera No Problem. I have voted up your question :)